# Show blob in iframe fails in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, blob

So, the gist is, I'm downloading uploaded files to the db to show them, at least most of them, inside a iframe

This is the code:

```
var ancho = $(window).width() * 0.90;
var alto = $(window).height() * 0.90;
$("#DialogoImagen").dialog({
    show: {
        effect: 'blind'
    },
    hide: {
        effect: 'blind'
    },
    width: ancho,
    height: alto,
    resizable: true,
    draggable: true,
    title: '',
    modal: true,
    position: { my: "center", at: "top", of: window }
});
$("#DialogoImagen").children().remove();
var iframe = $("<iframe width='98%' src='" + window.URL.createObjectURL(archivo) + "'/>");
$("#DialogoImagen").append(iframe);
```

Its nothing of the other world, I set the `iframe` `src` with a `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)`, works flawlessly with Chrome, FF, Opera, but, IE, even 11, is showing nothing, any idea what to do to solve it?

Comment: What's `archivo` exactly? What are you trying to achieve by setting the iframe src to it?

Comment: `archivo` would be the file's blob I received from my call to the server, which with createObjectUrl I generate a direct url to open the file

Comment: Sorry, I never got it to work, and I have far left that project months ago, but I'm pretty sure there might be a good tool or library already that takes care of this

Answer (score 1):

Depends what type of content you're working with, but since it's going in an `IFRAME` it's a fair bet that IE just doesn't support data URIs for that content type. [ref: caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri)

According to the above reference, IE supports images, CSS and script files, but *not* HTML. I can verify from personal experience that HTML data URLs, e.g.

```
data:text/html, <h1>Hi</h1><p>I'm a data URL
```

don't work in IE10.

Comment: Well, so far i'm only showing text, images and pdf, aside from that the rest is downloaded directly to the user